# How to re-install a VisualStudio extension: "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

I'd like to re-install a Visual Studio Extension that I had installed previously. It's not listed as an installed extension anymore in Tools->Extensions Manager->Installed Extensions->All, so I can't uninstall it via the GUI. When I try to download the extension and reinstall from the Visual Studio GUI, I get this error:

[image: Visual Studio error]

If I then use vsixinstaller to uninstall:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>vsixinstaller /u:"Tvl.VisualStudio.Framework.922dc49e-a1f8-43c2-a748-504c676ebbb6"
```

I get this error:

[image: vsixinstaller error]

I get the same error (with a corresponding ID) if I attempt to uninstall the other extensions:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>vsixinstaller /u:"Tvl.VisualStudio.OutputWindow.3EF11167-A319-43DB-B1B4-A9778A90FAE0"

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>vsixinstaller /u:"Tvl.VisualStudio.Language.Antlr3.74dda0ee-262e-4c58-8255-d57136664d2b"
```

How do I force the extension to uninstall so I can install it again?

Answer (score 0):

More recent versions of VS Allow you to reset the installation (via a devenv.exe command argument) - not sure if VS2010 does the same, but if not then you could install VS2012/13/15 (Community editon is free) which allows round-tripping of solutions between VS2010 and above.